# jQuery isn't working even though everything seems good to go, what's wrong with my code?

Tags: html, jquery, html5-video

I am trying to write simple jQuery play/pause buttons for a video in html5, but when I go and click the buttons, nothing happens. If you have any code for the play/pause functionality, I'd appreciate that very much.

Here's my code at the moment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js">
        
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#play').click(function(){
                $('#myvid').get(0).play();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <title>Drive</title>
</head>
<body>
   
    <video id="myvid" width="800" height="600">
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <track  src="leg.vtt" kind="captions" srclang="en-us" label="english" default>
    </video>

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="button" value="Play" id="play" />
    <input type="button" value="Pause" id="pause" />
    
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried multiple different codes but none of them caused nothing on the page, not even errors

Comment: You need two `<script>` tags. One for loading jQuery, and the second one for your script. You can't combine them into a single tag.

Comment: Try separating the script tags... so you'll have one just for <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script> and another for the doc ready function <script>code goes here</script>

Comment: There's also nothing in your script that needs jQuery, it's nearly identical with vanilla JS.

Comment: @DiogoMachado If the posted Answer below is solving your problem then you should **mark it as correct**. It shows thanks and also helps others to know that there is a solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my working example of JQuery code to play/pause a video:
https://codepen.io/sethuramancbe/pen/gOBRjmK

**(1)** Define a `<script>` tag for loading external JS files/libraries (*ie:* JQuery in this case):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
```

**(2)** Then define a separate `<script>` tag for code that handles Elements on the page:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#play").click( function() { $("#myvid").trigger("play"); } );

    $("#pause").click( function() { $("#myvid").trigger("pause"); } );
});

</script>
```